# MySQL using IN() with a tuple

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but just want to double check.

Obviously the normal use of IN() would be

```
UPDATE cars
SET colour = "Sunburst Red"
WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM cars WHERE colour LIKE "%Red%")
```

But what if I need to be more specific in my IN(), for example

```
UPDATE cars
SET colour = "Sunburst Red"
WHERE id, make IN(SELECT id, make FROM cars WHERE colour LIKE "%Red%" AND make like "Honda")
```

I know this is very much a Object Orientated style way of doing things and I highly doubt MySQL can do it but just on the off chance.

Comment: Can you come with a better example? Your first query should normally be written as `UPDATE cars SET colour = "Sunburst Red" WHERE colour LIKE "%Red%"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having touple in the IN is possible, you just need to add braces

`WHERE (id, make) IN(SELECT id, make FROM cars WHERE colour LIKE "%Red%" AND make like "Honda")`

Using the same table in a subselect of `update` however is danger and often not allowed. Your query could be rewritten as

```
UPDATE cars
SET colour = "Sunburst Red" WHERE `colour` LIKE "%Red%" AND `make` = "Honda"
```

Note: [it's possible that the query is not optimized in this way](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/04/04/multi-column-in-clause-unexpected-mysql-issue/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use two IN-blocks?

```
UPDATE cars
SET colour = "Sunburst Red"
WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM cars WHERE colour LIKE "%Red%" AND make like "Honda") 
AND
make IN(SELECT make FROM cars WHERE colour LIKE "%Red%" AND make like "Honda")
```

OK, it isn't the best style, and maybe not very fast, but a quick and dirty solution :D

Comment: I can't think of another way to achieve this than using those two IN's if you absolutely want to use IN. He could though, just issue a normal UPDATE statement like the one @linepogl shows in the comment to the question. I would just do something like this: ``UPDATE cars SET colour = "Sunburst Red" WHERE colour LIKE "%Red%" AND make LIKE "Honda"``

Answer (score 0):

your update though requires no such complexity as your sub query is on the same table.

you'd have to switch to something like:

```
UPDATE cars
SET colour = "Sunburst Red"
WHERE colour LIKE "%Red%" AND make like "Honda"
```

you might want to assess the impact of adding an index to the colour and make fields but if its an update rarely used its probably not worth it.

Comment: Sorry, it was a poor example.  I am using different tables.